# I'm Creating a File named "helloworld.txt" and saving some inputs but after I re run the code the contents that I save disappear.

Tags: java

[1 - This is the Input IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjryZ.png)

[2 - This is the Image with Input Saved Through Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3NMQ.png)

[3 - This is the IMAGE after I re-run the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqh18.jpg)

In the Third Picture I just re-run the main file without inputting anything but when I go and check the File it is empty.

If anything is missing or in any way you can help me I will be thankful to you.

This is my OOP project. As I don't want to remake those management system all over the Internet I chose this project and I want to create it easily as I can. I don't copy teachers work or any other Student I gain help from them but write a easy code for my own Understanding.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PortalTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedWriter in;
    BufferedReader in1;
    try {
        in = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("helloworld.txt"));
        in1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("helloworld.txt"));


        int moviesMenuInput;

        Portal portal = new Portal();
        Movies movies = new Movies();
        Games games = new Games();
        TvShows tvShows = new TvShows();
        Music music = new Music();

        portal.displayData();

        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int menuInput = input1.nextInt();


        moviesMenu:
        while (true)
        {
            switch (menuInput) {


                case 1:

                    System.out.println("1 - ADD MOVIES");
                    System.out.println("2 - REMOVE MOVIES");
                    System.out.println("3 - SEARCH MOVIES");
                    System.out.println("4 - RETURN TO MENU");

                    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);

                    moviesMenuInput = input2.nextInt();

                    switch (moviesMenuInput) {
                        case 1:

                            System.out.println("Enter Movie Name : ");

                            Scanner input6 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String addMoviesNameInput = input6.nextLine();

                            movies.setMovieName(addMoviesNameInput);
                            in.write(addMoviesNameInput);
                            in.newLine();


                            System.out.println("Enter Movie Release Date : ");

                            Scanner input7 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String addMoviesReleaseDateInput = input7.nextLine();
                            movies.setMovieReleaseDate(addMoviesReleaseDateInput);
                            in.write(addMoviesReleaseDateInput);
                            in.newLine();

                            System.out.println("Enter Movie Genre : ");

                            Scanner input8 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String addMoviesGenreInput = input8.nextLine();
                            movies.setMovieGenre(addMoviesGenreInput);
                            in.write(addMoviesGenreInput);
                            in.newLine();

                            System.out.println("Enter Movie Download Link : ");

                            Scanner input9 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String addMoviesDownloadLinkInput = input9.nextLine();
                            movies.setDownloadLink(addMoviesDownloadLinkInput);
                            in.write(addMoviesDownloadLinkInput);
                            in.newLine();

                            System.out.println("MOVIE ADDED");
                        in.close();
                            break;

                        case 2:

                            System.out.println("Enter Name of Movie to Delete : ");

                            Scanner input10 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String deleteMoviesInput = input10.nextLine();


                            if (deleteMoviesInput.equals(in1.readLine()))
                            {
                                System.out.println("MOVIE DELETED ! ");
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("NO MATCH FOUND");
                            }
                            in1.close();

                            break;
                        case 3:
                            System.out.println("Enter Name of Movie to Search : ");

                            Scanner input11 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String searchMoviesInput = input11.nextLine();

                            if(in1.readLine().equals(searchMoviesInput))
                            {
                                System.out.println("Movie Name : "+movies.getMovieName());
                                System.out.println("Movie Release Date : "+movies.getMovieReleaseDate());
                                System.out.println("Movie Genre : "+movies.getMovieGenre());
                                System.out.println("Movie Download Link : "+movies.getDownloadLink());
                            }

                            break;
                    }

                    continue moviesMenu;
            }


        }


    }catch(IOException e){

        System.out.println("There was a problem:" + e);

    }

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new FileWriter("helloworld.txt")
```

This constructor call creates a file if it does not exist, and opens it for writing. If the file already exists, this **truncates** the file and opens it for writing.

Hence your behavior: in the very beginning of your program you create your file or truncate it, and then you don't write anything to it (on the second run), so it remains empty.

I'd recommend to only invoke this constructor when you are actually going to write anything (so in your case, under `case 1`). You could do it like this:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("helloworld.txt"))) {
    // actually write to the writer
}
```

This way, the will be appropriately closed automatically after the execution leaves the `try` block.